# If textfield is empty do not send! - Help JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So to understand what I'm asking go to http://quicknews.99k.org/java_chat.html 
It's a chatbox that I've made with JavaScript.
When you click "send" it would keep sending... is there an if/else statement for JS?

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button').click(function(){
                    var message = $('textarea').val();
                    var old = $('#content').html();

                    $('#content').html(old + '<p>' + message);


                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that java and javascript are different things?

Comment: *"...is there an if/else statement for JS?"* Is that a serious question?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: No submit button nothing. no form to see. You want us to be psychics???

Comment: @SSS It's not a form. It's just using JS events. We don't have to be 'psychics' to read the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has if/else statement, you may try this

`$('button').click(function(){`

```
 var message = $('textarea').val();
 var old = $('#content').html();
 if(message.length==0) return false;
  $('#content').html(old + '<p>' + message);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var message = $('textarea').val();
    if (!message) return false;

    var old = $('#content').html();
    $('#content').html(old + '<p>' + message);
});
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bar any submit request when textarea is empty, try this:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(e){
                var message = $('textarea').val();
                var old = $('#content').html();
                //We are checking if the length of the message is zero
                if(message.length==0) 
                    //Cancel form submission
                    e.preventDefault();
                else {
                    $('#content').html(old + '<p>' + message);
                    //Empty the textbox when you are done
                    $('textarea').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the //Empty textarea when message sent !!

Comment: The text data in a chat application is destined to be sent to the server. As you can see, he isn't that good in javascript. He won't be able to use ajax request. So, in case he uses form submit, this code could help him.

Comment: @Parkhar Mishra can I have your skype, because I really want to learn more about this, please. Thanks.